# Use facebook send dialog without using any application

Tags: facebook, dialog, share, send

I am new to FB development, 
I wanted to share my application link through facebook and I am using send dialog.
It is working fine when I use the appID mentioned in the facebook doc.That app shows "via cool social app" message when loaded.I do not want to display that message.
What can be done?

Also I need to pre-populate the custom message which user can change if he wishes so.

Please help.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> That app shows "via cool social app" message when loaded.I do not want to display that message. What can be done?

Set up your own app, and use it’s app id.

If you *don’t* want to do that, or don’t want the *via appname* text to appear at all – then you *can’t* use this dialog; you could at most use the [Send button](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/send/) instead.

> Also I need to pre-populate the custom message

Not possible any more.